# Get `Instant` from `ZonedDateTime` in java.time

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

Given a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) in the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) of Java 8 and later, how does one obtain an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)?

Going the other way ( `Instant` → `ZonedDateTime` ) is simply:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId ) ;
```

Going from `ZonedDateTime` → `Instant` is needed for things like converting to the old-school [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class.

```
java.util.Date date = Date.fromInstant( instant ) ;
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [`toInstant()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--) **default** method from [`ChronoZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html) interface (which is inherited by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

[image: screenshot of documentation page for ChronoZonedDateTime class with method toInstant highlighted]

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that method name tucked under the "Methods inherited from…" block.

Comment: @BasilBourque Doesn't your browser support `ctrl + f` or `cmd + f`? :P

Comment: @Tom Yes, my web browser does indeed support *Command+F*. Found 70 occurrences of *Instance*. I looked at every hit in the list of main methods. Twice. If you look at the doc pages for `Instant`, `Date`, and `java.sql.Timestamp` you’ll notice that virtually none of the inter-type conversion methods are inherited, they are all in the main method list.

Comment: @BasilBourque Well the class is called `Instant`, not `Instance` :P. Also some IDEs also support a good auto complete feature where can write something like `myZonedDateTime.` and if you then write `instant` it would find the method `toInstant`. ... well at least IntelliJ can do that :D.